# Right click menu in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-calendar

Is it possible to implement right click menu in SharePoint calendar view?

Comment: Can you please add more details regarding what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: When right click on calendar content type list item, I need to load right click menus..